# Casting a ListBox items to Color

Tags: c#, winforms, casting, .net

In my application, depending on needs, Some `TabPage`s will be added to a `TabControl` programatically. Each page will contain a `ListView` and two `ListBox`es:

```
//Color Picker
var colorBox = new ListBox
{
    DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof (KnownColor)),
    Height = 40,
    Width = tabFiles.Width/3,
    Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
};

page.Controls.Add(colorBox);

//Style Picker
var styleBox = new ListBox
{
    DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SymbolType)),
    Height = 40,
    Width = tabFiles.Width / 3,
    Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
};

page.Controls.Add(styleBox);
```

Now later I want to send the selected color and symbol to another class using the code below, it compiles but at runtime it fires invalid cast. How can I fix this?

```
Color color = (Color)((ListBox)tabFiles.TabPages[i].Controls[1]).SelectedItem;
SymbolType symbol = (SymbolType)((ListBox)tabFiles.TabPages[i].Controls[2]).SelectedItem;
```

P.S: I know that color and symbol are added to page with index 1 and 2 respectivly.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the relation between `typeof (KnownColor)` and `Color color`? Or is it just a typo? Also could you please provide the message of the invalid cast exception?

Comment: Error message is `Specified cast is not valid.` That `typeof (KnownColor)` Returns all the colors as a datasource for listbox, same for SymbolType. at seconde code I am trying to make a color out of selected color name in the listbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a perfectly valid runtime exception. `System.Drawing.KnownColor` is an `enum` which you are casting to a `System.Drawing.Color` which is a `struct`, they are two very different types.

The hint is in your own code. You are setting the `DataSource` of your `ListBox` from an enumeration:

```
DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof (KnownColor))
```

If you cannot change your data source, I suggest you convert from KnownColor to Color before casting using the `Color.FromKnownColor()` method.